# What makes this saved array different from the loaded array?

Tags: c, arrays, json

I have this function that saves the entire array ia into a file called 'filename' in a JSON text file array file format:

```
int intarr_save_json( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    if(ia==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int *arr=ia->data;
    int n=ia->len;
    int i;
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen(filename,"w");
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        fprintf(p,"[\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i!=n-1)  
            {
                fprintf(p," %d,\n",arr[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(p," %d\n",arr[i]);
            }
        }
        fprintf(p,"]");
        fclose(p);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And this function that loads a new array from the file called 'filename', that was
 previously saved using intarr_save().

```
intarr_t* intarr_load_json( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) return NULL;

    intarr_t* loaded = intarr_create(0);

    int value;
    //Get rid of [
    fscanf(f, "%c ", &value);

    while (fscanf(f, "%d, ", &value)) {
        if (value == ']') break;
        intarr_push(loaded, value);
    }


    fclose(f);
    return loaded;
}
```

It all seems nice, but, for some reason, the length of the loaded array is not the same as the length of the saved array. What could be causing this?

EDIT: Now my function is like this

```
int intarr_save_json( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    if(ia == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int *arr=ia->data;
    int n=ia->len;
    int i;
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen(filename,"w");
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        fprintf(p,"[\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i!=n-1)  
            {
                fprintf(p," %d,\n",arr[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(p," %d\n",arr[i]);
            }
        }
        fprintf(p,"]");
        fclose(p);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

and
intarr_t* intarr_load_json( const char* filename )
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    intarr_t* loaded = intarr_create(0);

    int value;


    char line[100];
    while ( fgets(line, 100, f) )
    {
        if ( line[0] == ']' )
           {
            break;
           }

        if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &value) != 1 )
            {
              break;
            }

    // Use the number
    intarr_push(loaded, value);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return loaded;
}
```

But now the load always return a null pointer. What could be causing this?

Comment: Let me guess, the loaded array is *one* smaller than the actual array? Take a look at the format you pass to `fscanf`, and remember that except white-space extra characters must be matched exactly (which includes the comma in your format).

Comment: `if(value == ']')` is the same as `if(value == 93)` which somehow I doubt is what you wanted. So you stop reading values if there's a 93 in the array.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to detect other file errors from the `fscanf` call as you only loop while `fscanf` returns non-zero. If there's an error then `fscanf` will return `EOF` which is `-1`. Furthermore, `value` will *never* be equal to `']'`, the character `']'` is not a decimal number so `fscanf` will never read it using the `"%d"` format. Lastly a word of warning: Don't use trailing space in a `scanf` format, it requires there's either end-of-file or something non-space following the white-space. Usually works fine for files but not generally.

Comment: It's weird... When the len is 75, the loaded and saved array have the same value. This seems so random

Comment: Finally, don't try to make a JSON saving and loading library yourself, it's much to much work considering that there are so many corner-cases and behaviors that can go wrong. It's also a lot of code to write (that *will* contain bugs), especially if you want to be able to handle generic JSON objects. Find a library which will handle it for you, there are many available if you search a little. It will make your life as a programmer much simpler if you don't reinvent the wheel every time.

Comment: I changed my code, but now it's always returning a null pointer on load function. That's odd

Answer (score 1):

The logic used in

```
while (fscanf(f, "%d, ", &value)) {
    if (value == ']') break;
```

is flawed.

The last two lines of your file will be

```
<some number>
]
```

The call to `fscanf` will fail at that line. Hence, you will end up reading one less number than you wrote to the file.

I suggest changing the strategy a bit.

```
// Read the contents of the file line by line
// Process each line.
char line[100];
while ( fgets(line, 100, f) )
{
    if ( line[0] == ']' )
    {
       break;
    }

    if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &value) != 1 )
    {
       break;
    }

    // Use the number
    intarr_push(loaded, value);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So the problem is only with the loading function, not with the saving function? I'll check that out and see how it goes. It seems reasonable. Thank you

Comment: @Mil3d, that's my assessment.

Comment: Hey, I changed my code as per your suggestion, but now the load is always returning a null pointer. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @Mil3d, what do you mean by that? Is the call to `fgets` returning `NULL` always?

Comment: Or should I delete fscanf?

Comment: To read and discard the `[` at the top of the file, use a variable of type `char`, not `int`. `char value; fscanf(f, "%c ", &value);`. You can also use `fgets()` and discard that line.

Comment: Basically, just change int to char? I'll try and see how it goes. Last time I tried, the load function was returning NULL for everything, but maybe it was a mistake of mine

Answer (score 0):

You must read one non space character after each integer, and stop reading when it is a closing brace `']'` instead of a comma `','`.
 So your reading loop should be:

```
do {
    char sep[2];
    int cr = fscanf(f, "%d%1s", &value, sep)) { /* read one value and the separator */
    if (cr != 2) {
        /* signal the error, exit, ... */
    }
    intarr_push(loaded, value); /* always push the value */
} while (sep[0]== ']') break;    /* loop until the separator if a ] */
```